# How to use Ionic Native Player in real use case

Tags: ios, angular, audio, ionic-framework, ionic3

I need to play a lite mp3 file in my Ionic App.
I tried to use Native Audio from Ionic : [Ionic Native Audio Playback](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-audio/)

But it doesn't work on iOS emulator.
When I call this function from /MyIonicApp/src/pages/home/home.ts :

```
this.nativeAudio.preloadSimple('BellId', '../../../resources/sounds/bell.mp3')
.then(onSuccess => {
    this.soundLoaded = true;
    console.log('preloadSimple : ' + onSuccess);
}, onError => {
    console.error('preloadSimple : ' + onError);
});
```

I have this error :

```
console.error: preloadSimple : (NATIVE AUDIO) Asset not found. (../../../resources/sounds/bell.mp3)
```

But file bell.mp3 is really in this path : MyIonicApp/resources/sounds/
Why it doesn't found my mp3 file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your problem is with the `path`.Put your `mp3` file on `assets` folder and then access it as below.

**i.e.** `assets -->  sounds --> bell.mp3`

```
this.nativeAudio.preloadSimple('BellId', './assets/sounds/bell.mp3').then(onSuccess => {
    this.soundLoaded = true;
    console.log('preloadSimple : ' + onSuccess);
}, onError => {
    console.error('preloadSimple : ' + onError);
});
```

Comment: Ok, I understand, the resources folder is not reachable from Angular code. I tested, it's running fine ! Thanks !